# Why do tribe members cover their private parts

Tags: sexuality, anthropology

I find it perfectly logical, that the humans felt cold and began to wear clothes. However, In many tribes in Africa, South America and Asia, where the traditional clothing is a Loincloth only, which obviously does not keep warm. I never heard from a tribe that is completely naked.

The question I have is... why? It is obvious that the answer has to be sexuality since well, that's what the private parts are for. But why is the urge that not everybody can see ones private part so deeply anchored in human behavior?

Basically, there is no need to cover and it will take resources and workpower to create clothes. I find it odd that even non of the most separated tribes got rid of this social convention.

Thanks for answers

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the Philosophy SE. This questioned doesn't seem to be about philosophy, but more about anthropology or psychology.

Comment: The chief had to have the largest member. If everyone covers up, this illusion can be preserved. Also when one is hunting, the private parts could get hung up in the briars, or burrs can get caught in the hair and so in. Then to, someone could put a magic spell on your privates, or give them the evil eye and cause all kinds of problems. Plus the life spirit is in the privates and you don't want it to leak out. All kinds of spirits are swirling around down there.

Comment: To bring this up to date: Freud, Civilization and its discontents; Marcuse, Eros and Civilization; works also by Norbert Elias and Alan Wheelis.  What we are seeing is a break and move away from the animal which is the price we pay for Civilization, but of course it's a terrible price in some ways. Much gets suppressed but it does not disappear.

Comment: In addition to the main function of [Clothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clothing#Functions): the protective one, we must consider also the social and cultural ones: mainly, social status and gender differentiation.

Comment: Do primitive tribe members cover their members? Or do we only believe that because they're portrayed that way in the movies?

Comment: @user4894  Good observation, but if you look at photographs most all I have seen have some covering. Of course at some point in evolution we are all naked, and as Alexander says this is mainly for anthropology and psychology to study. There is however overlap with philosophy, e.g. philosophical anthropology (L. Klages, et. Al), and Frankfurt School, Marcuse, Fromm. In urban industrial society, nudity is outside the camp, (outside of order)i.e. usually in nature. Mircea Eliade, The Myth of the Eternal Return is suggestive here.

Comment: I emphasize outside the city limits. Adorno got a dose of the female form in his classroom when some young ladies exposed themselves to him (the 1969 Busenaktion), and I think it shook him up pretty bad, or he pretended it did.

Comment: There is a strong social need to cover private parts given the psychological urges of sexuality. Having them exposed would be an emotionally fueled distraction from less arousing mundane tasks that need to be performed. But as remarked above, this is not a question about philosophy.

Comment: If we have the ordering of existing primitive tribes in degree of evolution correct, then the Amerinds are he oldest.  So before loincloths, you get penis sheaths, which provide only a reinforcement for the foreskin, and there are various coverings worn only to do certain kinds of work.  When not doing that work, e.g. cooking, women go naked and men wrap the ends of their foreskins.  So it is reasonable to assume clothing is not initially about warmth, but about keeping bugs off the glans of the penis in times before it was possible to really stay clean.